# Inverse Function Theorem and Hessians Matrices

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

> Let $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{2}$ and $b \in V$ a critical point of $f$. If $\varphi: U \to V$ is a diffeomorphism $C^{2}$ with $\varphi(a) = b$, then the hessian of $f$ in the point $b$ and the hessian of $f \circ \varphi$ in the point $a$ has a same rank.

I wanted a way to go. I tried to do some things, but I didn't have a good ideas. I know I need to use Inverse Function Theorem, but I don't know how to use it. I don't want a solution for the question, I just want an idea to continue. Thanks for the advance!

**EDIT** (because of Daniele's comment). I have to use the Inverse Function Theorem and this implies that $\varphi$ is a local diffeomorphism iff $\varphi'(x): U \to V$ is an isomorphism $\forall x \in U$ so, I can understand that $\nabla\varphi: TU_{x} \to TV_{\varphi(x)}$ is an isomorphism. But I still cannot see how to use this to conclude the question. Is probably a little detail that I cannot see.

Comment: Could you use the fact that $\nabla\varphi: TU_x\to TV_{\varphi(x)}$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, thus the rank of the Hessian of $f$ determines the rank of the whole composition $f\circ\varphi$?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, I have to use the Inverse Function Theorem and this implies that $\varphi$ is a local diffeomorphism iff $\varphi'(x): U \to V$ is an isomorphism $\forall x \in U$ so, I can understand the isomorphism you mentioned. I apologize, but I still cannot see how to use this to conclude the question. Is probably a little detail that I cannot see.

Comment: You can prove that in an easier way, i.e. without recourse to the implicit function theorem, by simply noting that $$\nabla \varphi\circ\varphi^{-1}(x)=\nabla \varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi(x)=\boldsymbol{1}$$ where $\boldsymbol{1}$ is the identity matrix. Then you can explicit the resulting matrix product at the left side and proceed as pointed out by @ChrisCuster. I apologize for not giving all the details, but I wanted to respect your requests: next time I'll try give more details, or at least try to be more understandable.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, your comment was pertinent, the probleme was I have forgotten the result about the rank of the composition. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe,  based on what you have, that you just need a fact from linear algebra...

Namely,  if $T$ is a linear transformation,  and $I$ an isomorphism,  then $\operatorname{rank}({T\circ I})=\operatorname{rank}T$.

This follows from the fact that $I(V)=V$ and $\operatorname{rank}T=\dim(\operatorname{image}T)$...

So, let $T$ be your Hessian at a point $a$;  and $I$ the isomorphism, $\phi'$,from the tangent space at point $a$ to point $\phi(a)=b$, where $\phi$ is your diffeomorphism...

Comment: Of course! I didn't pay attention. Thank you!

Comment: Where did the hypothesis about $b$ being a critical point was used?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin it seems it would also be true for a regular point. A critical point was perhaps mentioned because the Hessian is used to classify critical points.